# In which file to add the cache_clear_all function

Tags: 7, blocks, caching

In my situation I would like a certain block on my page with real time information to not be cached for anonymous users. Literature listed below:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/42055
- https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/beginners-guide-caching-data-drupal-7

  suggests using the

> cache_clear_all('modulename', 'cache')

I added this on my module inside the hook_block_view() function. This does not work though. Any directions on where I can use this function.

Here is the function information:

Clearing specific entries in cache tables 
The Drupal cache API can be used to clear specific items. Caching back ends can be switched (to memcache, to flat files, etc.) without having to rewrite any code.

```
cache_clear_all('content:' . $MYNID, 'cache_content', TRUE);
```

The example above clears all items from cache that start with 'content:$MYNID*'. To ONLY remove one specific row, drop the $wildcard parameter (the "TRUE" statement in the function call) and change the format of the first parameter to omit the asterisk, which functions as a wildcard.

```
cache_clear_all('content:' . $MYNID . ':' . $MYNID, 'cache_content');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the block's caching in `hook_block_info`, like so:

```
function MODULE_block_info()
{
    $blocks = array();

    $blocks["BLOCK_NAME"] = array(
        "info"  => "BLOCK TITLE",
        "cache" => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );

    return $blocks;
}
```